# Warning: gzdecode(): data error in php

Tags: php, gzip

I know this question already asked, but I can't solve my problem, so I explained my problem here kindly help me to solve this.

I am getting data form this example URL by using file_get_contens()

```
$URL1 = 'abcd.com/xxx';
$URL2 = 'abcd.com/yyy';
$URL3 = 'abcd.com/zzz';

$response1 = file_get_contents($URL1);
$response2 = file_get_contents($URL2);
$response3 = file_get_contents($URL3);
```

And I compressed response data using gzencode because data too long and added prefix for my reference 
then i save compressed data to DB

```
$arrayResponse['URL1'] = '_|_coMpResSed_|_' . gzencode($response1);
$arrayResponse['URL2'] = '_|_coMpResSed_|_' . gzencode($response2);
$arrayResponse['URL3'] = '_|_coMpResSed_|_' . gzencode($response3);
```

**DB details**

- Storage Engine : InnoDB
- Collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Type : longblob or longtext (both i tried)

And I decompress the data by using gzdecode

```
$temp1 = explode('_|_coMpResSed_|_', $arrayResponse['URL1']);
$temp2 = explode('_|_coMpResSed_|_', $arrayResponse['URL2']);
$temp3 = explode('_|_coMpResSed_|_', $arrayResponse['URL3']);

if (!empty($temp1[1]) && !empty($temp2[1]) && !empty($temp3[1])) {
    $arrayResponse['URL1'] = gzdecode($temp1[1]);//working fine 
    $arrayResponse['URL2'] = gzdecode($temp2[1]);// getting warning 
    $arrayResponse['URL3'] = gzdecode($temp3[1]);//working fine     
}
```

And I am getting `Warning:

> gzdecode(): data error`on line`$arrayResponse['URL2'] = gzdecode($temp2[1]);`

Other lines are working fine . I dont know where I am making mistakes. Can any one help me to get this?

Comment: You are overwriting $temp2.

Comment: sorry that actually $temp3 not $temp2 now i edited

Comment: You should use a BLOB type - but one important thing is how are you inserting and retrieving the data from the DB?  Are some values being escaped going in and not getting unescaped coming out?

Comment: Tested your code and it works fine. Probably your data gets corrupted when saving it to db or fetching from db.

Comment: I stored each data to each row in DB and I am getting data by each row from db ... And are charset or collation make any problem ?

Comment: Please add the code used for storing and retrieving the data.

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake before saving DB I am doing real escape string in mysql so zip file get corrupted .. so now i am corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Having same problem, I just had a look at Mysql doc: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

*Many encryption and compression functions return strings for which the result might contain arbitrary byte values. If you want to store these results, use a column with a **VARBINARY** or **BLOB** binary string data type. This will avoid potential problems with trailing space removal or character set conversion that would change data values, such as may occur if you use a nonbinary string data type (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT).*

I just change the column data type to VARBINARY and everything's OK.