# Performing mysql_real_escape_string for gzencod data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to save `gzencode()` data to my database, before that Normally I am doing mysql_real_escape_string  while saving data into db ...

For that, It adding `/`to every `'` single quotation of zipped string before saving to database ...

so I am getting error while performing gzdecode I explained that my previous question 
[here link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028844/warning-gzdecode-data-error-in-php)

To solve problem I converted zipped string to base64encode format.

Now my question is How to save zipped data to database with real escaped format?

Comment: Do you have to use real escape string?

Comment: Yes I have to use real escape string for to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You should use parameterizee queries to avoid sql injection